# SSH tectia - Still need password when there is private key? (Setting)

Tags: ssh

I am confused on setting the private key on ssh tectia. I imported the private key and key in the info's and when trying to connect. It prompt out a box and request for password as shown below. I try to key in the private key password or leave it blank but is incorrect. I already set the permission of file transfer to 755. I am using Windows 7.

Anyone know what to key in?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the private key pair is expired. The SSH client defaults to password authentication when the key authentication fails. meaning your current private key is no longer valid for login

Check if the date on your server and pc is correct. 
if you can, regenerate another private key pair and import. tutorial here https://support.ssh.com/manuals/client-user/61/userauth-pk-gui.html